# Django audio, video and image upload

Tags: django

I have trying to solve this problem for so long somebody please please please help me. So I am a newbie I'm django and I am learning it. I made an app where you can upload files. I have used the filefield in my models but the problem is  if I want to upload a image file I have to use the img tag in html and if I want to upload a video I have to use the video tag and similarly for audio I have to use the audio tag but the problem is if I upload a video it won't show in img tag and vice versa. So how do I make that the user just upload a file and it automatically use the required tag in html just like instagram, you can upload video audio image. If any one knows anything please help please please please.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a property in your model that return filetype and you can use it to identify whether it is a video, audio or image.

Something like this

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='file_path')

    def extension(self):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)
        return extension
```

even you can do

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='file_path')

    def extension(self):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)
        if extension in ['mp3', 'wav', ...]:
            return 'audio'
        if extension in ['mp4', 'mpg', 'mpeg', ...]:
            return 'video'
        if extension in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png' ....]:
            return 'image'
```

Hope this will help you out :)